# Unreal 5 Actor Can't Move

Tags: movement, ai, unreal, unreal-5

I have an Unreal 5 actor with some basic blueprints involving a "Simple Move to Location".

[image]

I've created a NavMeshBoundsVolume, and both the actor and destination point are inside it.  The actor's mesh isn't inside any other mesh, except for the nav volume.

[image]

Yet, when I run the game, the enemy doesn't move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - The "Controller" slot in the Move can't be empty, which isn't intuitively clear.  I used a Get Controller node and set the target to Self.

[image]

2 - Completely separate from the node graph, there's this idea of "Components" in the blueprint, which is new to me.  My pawn needed a FloatingPawnMovement component, which I added via the left panel.

[image]

3 - From the output log, `DefaultSceneRoot has to be 'Movable' if you'd like to move it with FloatingPawnMovement.`  I was able to change that in the main outliner.

DefaultSceneRoot → Transform → Mobility → Movable

Those three changes together fixed the issue.